# Migrating to TypeScript, __dirname sets to the dist folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to migrate to TypeScript, where I did not write any `.ts` files yet. The generated code in the `dist` folder does not include non-js files like .xml, .json, etc. The problem is now that when running the application and tying to have access to those files, `__dirname` has the path to the `dist` foler.

the code is something like this

```
const file= fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../folder', 'file.sql')).toString();
```

Is this the expected behavior? How should I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the expected behaviour as the `__dirname` points to where you are. The solution for this would be to either [copy the files](https://vccolombo.github.io/blog/tsc-how-to-copy-non-typescript-files-when-building/) or assume that you are going to have a `dist` folder.